# trying to create this texture with blender for 3d printing

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to recreate this texture on blender for 3d printing however I am having difficulty achieving the raised parts of the hollows.The below image is the closest I am getting. Any tips?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42640/is-it-possible-to-use-a-displacement-map-without-having-real-geometry. Generally you probably want to use **Subsurf** modifier to enlargen amount of verts and then **Displace** to make those hollows.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41030/deforming-a-maze-mesh-into-a-hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Tissue](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue) add-on for this.

Create a quad mesh with the contours you want, then create a tile object that is a pit.

Select the tile object, then the contour object and press the Tessellate button. A new mesh will created with your perfect pits where each quad face was.

You'll want to keep the Scale value low, and enable the Merge option so each tile will be connected.

[image: Creating pit or groove topology using the Tissue add-on]

You can then smooth the shading and add a SubSurf modifier to get something very close to your reference photo.

[image: Smoothing out the pits with a SubSurf modifier]

Comment: @SarahONeill Good luck, and happy blending!

Comment: @SarahONeill Glad to hear it worked out for you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just like Mr Zac said you should add more resolution with a subsurf modifier and then add a displacement modifier and find an image texture to use as the displacement value. the image needs to have highs and lows in the correct places in order to get the effect you want. if what you need is so specific then you might need to create a custom image.

Example image:
[image]

Resulting Effect
[image]

Same mesh in edit mode... as you can see it is a simple low res plane. the subsurf modifier adds the resolution you need. the displacement modifier does the bumps.
[image]

EDIT: if you don't understand how to setup textures for displacement ask and i can help.

Comment: sorry about that... as i was working on my answer another person posted one.

Comment: Hi I tried it too.. but the mesh im working on has to be 20cm by 20cm and when I place the texture on the plane it looks tiny.I tried scaling it up on the mapping section but still too small.I also tried scaling up the texture image too but still same size on mesh.

Comment: Can you give screenshots of the process?